# Does Egypt have the right to attack the Ethiopian dam?

Tags: egypt

Reading about the ownership of the dam, found that the control and final say on any projects on the dam belongs to Egypt.

Does this give Egypt the right to attack the Ethiopian dam?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Ethiopian_Renaissance_Dam

Comment: What dam? Can you give a bit more context and maybe a citation for your claims of Egyptian control?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not mediate questions of international law with little to no precedent on this website. This is a completely opinon-based question.

Comment: "... final say on any projects on the dam belongs to Egypt."  What is that based on?  Ethiopia was not a party to either the 1929 agreement between Egypt and Great Britain-controlled African colonies in the Nile basin nor the 1959 agreement between Egypt and Sudan.

Comment: @Philipp Maybe this question is on-topic.  There is an applicable set of international rules, so answers might not have to be entirely opinion-based:  [**Berlin Rules on Water Resources**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Rules_on_Water_Resources)  And there are documented cases throughout history where control of water flow was literally used as acts of war.

Comment: *the right* doesn't mean much.  Doubt any international body would *recognize* a physical attack as justified.  Egypt certainly has the right to drag the case in for arbitration, which seems to have been done already.  And it can also attack if it wishes to do so, but it's not going to get an international seal of approval out of it, as the OP most likely well knows already.  Plus, I rather doubt the story is as clear-cut as it gets presented here. My understanding is a) dam is on Ethiopian territory b) dispute is largely about how quickly dam gets filled up i.e. how much water % cutoff

Comment: @JustMe I think it definitely can be on-topic, but I think it needs to be clarified a bit. Like you said, I'm not sure where they got that the final say belongs to Egypt – and that's kind of central to the question. They should either ask about that, and leave the right to attack to another question, or support that claim.

Comment: that doesnt sound anything like a UN-recognized right of defense kinda case.  Of course, wars happen all the time with/wo UN green light, but that's just the point, they are not "legit" wars, whatever that means or does not mean.

Comment: Voted to re-open because we've got a good answer below that deals with the generalities of international rights and consequences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you're talking about countries, "rights" means something very different.  A country's "rights" are defined by what other countries let them do.  Sometimes this is by treaty, sometimes by threat of war or economic restrictions, sometimes it's simply by generally accepted convention, and sometimes it's simply because there would be no effective action to counter it.  There's no higher power to enforce anything - even the UN and its constituent bodies only works (as much as they do) because the countries involved agreed to go along with it.

Given that, the real question is whether other countries would accept the dam as a *[casus belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli)* for attacking another country.  If they do, then Egypt has the "right" to make that attack.  If they don't, then Egypt doesn't have that "right", but can still do so anyway, if they're willing to suffer the international consequences.  Either way, Ethiopia has the "right" to defend itself and its infrastructure, because territorial self-defense is a [internationally recognized right of a country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defence_in_international_law).